# plain python script vs robot framework vs python script with web ui

Tags: python, django, automated-tests, robotframework, rpa

I have a task to create a validation testing for new firmware builds of firewalls (do upgrade and test all firewall features ), i have a good Python knowledge . and need users to have any kind of UI for the test .

i am confused which method to use .
1- Python scripts with logging and execute it from Jenkins .
2- robot framework which has its own reporting and run it from Jenkins .
3- python script with Django web UI .

i'v done part of the project with robot framework which has a very limited documetation and info on the internet . i cannot do certain tasks as it gets complex . i am in love with it's reporting but at some point felt it is not worth it .

now i am trying to redo this part with normal python scripts .

Comment: Personal recommendation: don't use Robot Framework.

Comment: so what are the options to get a good logging with ui

Comment: This question if more like invitation for discussion than something that has one correct answer. For discussion of robot framework concepts and limitation I would suggest to go to official robot framework forum.

Comment: _"robot framework which has a very limited documetation and info on the internet "_ - why do you think that? The [userguide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)  is extremely comprehensive, and every keyword library has documentation for every keyword.

Comment: @Wilson: why not robotframework? Giving an opinion like that without backing it up with a reason is not very useful.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought of writing up an answer to this but don't think I could do the question justice, not having used Python for testing a whole lot. I saw that OP indicated some hesitation as to whether Robot Framework was "worth it" and wanted to motivate him to go with his gut feeling. Robot Framework has very unwieldy syntax, unintuitive behavior, and gaping holes in its libraries, and in my experience using it, I find I spend half my time cobbling together `Evaluate` statements in order to use actual Python because RF keywords are too obtuse for the job. So why not just use Python?